# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)| \le |z^2+5|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Determine $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)| \le |z^2+5|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Determine $f$.

How to apply Liouville's Theorem in this question?

Comment: Think of applying Cauchy's estimate for the coefficients of the power series of $f$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^2 + 5}$$

We have $f(-5i) = f(5i) = 0$, so expanding $f$ in power series near $-5i$ and $5i$, we see that $h$ has a removable singularity at each of the two points. Hence $h$ is entire. We have $|h| \le 1$, so by Liouville's theorem, $h = c$. Hence $f = c(z^2 + 5)$. As $f(0) = 1$, we get $c = 1/5$.

Comment: Why is it that $f(\pm5i) = 0 \implies h(z)$ has removable singularities at $\pm5i$?

Comment: @RSerrao $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\pm 5i)}{n!} (z-\pm 5i)^n$, so as $f(\pm5i)=0$, $f(z) = f'(\pm 5i) (z-\pm 5i) + \frac{f''(\pm 5i)}{2} (z-\pm 5i)^2 + \cdots$

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the downvoter would explain. I am not too sure of my answer anyway.

Comment: It wasn't me; I am also reasoning about your answer.